# Trigraphs not compiling with MS compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, trigraphs

I have a C++14 project withe the Microsoft compiler in Visual Studio 2019 and I'm trying to understand Digraphs and Trigraphs, so my code is a bit weird:

```cpp
#include "Trigraphs.h"

void Trigraphs::assert_graphs()
??<
    // How does this ever compile ????/
    ouch!
??>
```

Reading about the [/Zc:trigraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-trigraphs-trigraphs-substitution?view=msvc-170) switch

> Through C++14, trigraphs are supported as in C. The C++17 standard removes trigraphs from the C++ language.

I understand that trigraphs should be supported until C++14 because they were removed in C++17 only. Yet, the above code does not compile with C++14 settings until I add the additional command line switch. I am not a native English speaker, did I get something wrong about the sentence that trigraphs are supported until C++14?

Comment: If you want trigraph support, you'll need the `/Zc:trigraphs` compiler switch.  As per MSDN: "The `/Zc:trigraphs` option is off by default"

Comment: You just discovered that the "C++14 mode" in several compilers is not actually fully conformant to the C++14 standard, and that another flag is needed. Why isn't the simplest configuration (no additional flag) causing the full compliance with C++14? Well, because most programmers would actually prefer to work in a non-conformant "C++14 sans trigraphs" than in a fully conformant "C++14", so it is more convenient to make the former as the "default". C++17 realized this and made it official, at last.

Comment: @chi: I definitely think it's worth turing that off, since I can hardly understand the code I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-trigraphs-trigraphs-substitution?view=msvc-170) also says:

> The `/Zc:trigraphs` option is off by default

and that seems to apply for C++14 already. Although that results in a non 100% conformant C++ compilation, most programmers will actually prefer not dealing with the strange symbols of C++ trigraphs.